# remove char in string at many specific index when index are in the list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to remove character from string `seq_in = 'KPKPAJDSKGRPRRKAPPP'` at specific indices in the list `ind = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]`. The result should be `'AJDSGA'`. I tried `remove()` the string by looping the `ind` list, but each character's index was shifted.

How to remove many characters at index from the list without loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `join` using `enumerate` to get the index of each letter. If the index isn't in `ind` then keep it.

```
>>> ''.join(j for i,j in enumerate(seq_in) if i not in ind)
'AJDSGA'
```

As mentioned in the comments, your lookups will be faster if `ind` is a `set` than if it stays a `list`

```
>>> ind = {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18}
>>> ''.join(j for i,j in enumerate(seq_in) if i not in ind)
'AJDSGA'
```

Comment: suggestion: make `ind` a set